# OpenSSL what to do after creating the CA certificate

Tags: apache, openssl, digital-certificate, ca

i've created a self signed CA with DSA using OpenSSL and created a .der file using x509 of openSSL.
I can create user certificate requests, verify them and create user certificates. can create signature and verify them also.
but what to do with the .der file? i can do all the above things with .cert or .pem files. .der supposed to be shown side to the browser address bar. how to install that?

i'm using PHP and Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it. i need to install the .der in my server using config files of apache-openssl.
i've tried that with xampp. initially it worked for the 1st time. i installed the cert files in the browsers. and got the public shown for the page from the address bar.

later when i restarted apache, the whole xampp was crashed and i'was unable to start apache. i needed to re-install xampp and then i'm able to start apache again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read that : 
[DER vs. CRT vs. CER vs. PEM Certificates and How To Convert Them](http://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them)